# How to change .carousel-control-next-icon hover color

Tags: bootstrap-4, controls, carousel

Which css property controls the hover color for the bootstrap 4 carousel control icons - ".carousel-control-next-icon" & ".carousel-control-prev-icon"?

Answer (score 0):

The Carousel icon arrows use SVG images. You can change the `fill` attribute as needed with a HEX, RGBA, named color etc...

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=...' fill='#ffcc00' ...);
}

.carousel-control-next-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=...' fill='cyan' viewBox='...');
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/s9QQJY5uDU

Another option is to use a font icon such as Fontawesome, Feather Icons, etc...